# Orientable cover of a non-orientable manifold factored through the orientation double cover.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, orientation

While proving that orientable cover $M$ of a manifold non-orientable manifold $N$ factored through the orientation double cover, I got stuck in this following problem...

If $p:N→M$ is a covering, N orientable, then $ \pi_M∘\pi_1(p)=\pi_N $ where $\pi_N$ is the morphism $\pi_1(N)→Z/2$, sending loops to the orientation of the base point according to lifts in the orientation double cover. $\pi_M$ is also defined in similar fashion. The covering map $p$ induced $\pi_1(p):\pi_1(N)\to \pi_1(M) $.

Intuitively it is clear to me, but I want a precise proof, which I am missing somehow.

Comment: Your question has several typographical errors and undefined notation. You've defined $\pi_N$, but what is $\pi_M$? What is $\pi_1$? Why do you mention $\pi(M)$ which is not mentioned elsewhere?

Comment: @LeeMosher I've fixed them

Comment: @LeeMosher can you provide me some idea about this problem. Actually I could not able to write down a proper proof of this problem.

Comment: Your description of the homomorphism $\pi_N : \pi_1(N) \to \mathbb{Z}/2$ does not sound at all correct. What it should say is that for each element $[\gamma] \in \pi_1(N)$ represented by a loop $\gamma$ with both ends at the base point of $N$, $\pi_N(\gamma)$ is the trivial element of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ if $\gamma$ preserves orientation, and $\pi_N(\gamma)$ is the nontrivial element if $\gamma$ reverses orientation. So you'll need to understand the definition of "$\gamma$ preserves orientation", which you can get from whatever textbook you are reading.